# PHP display blob from DB

Tags: php, blob

i just want to display my DB blob in my web page to make a profile picture but it doesn't work, it displays my img in a full tab but i want to display my img as an  tag to put other information in my page.

```
public function getBlob(){
    $stmt = MyPDO::getInstance()->prepare("SELECT * FROM prj_img where id = 1 ");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $_GET['id']);
    $stmt->execute();


    $blob= $stmt->fetch();
    $img = $blob['name']; //myBlob
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    echo $blob['data'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your images are really stored as blobs in the DB (this is unusual), then you need a script that displays them as an image, and then get your image from there.

So the code you posted (which has an `image/jpeg` header) should be a separate image page. For example, `get_image.php`.

After then you can use `<img src="get_image.php" />` on other pages.

Naturally you will probably want some input to determine which image to show, which will also require input validation.

Answer (score 0):

You should try img tag to show picture from DB blob like following

```
public function getBlob(){
    $stmt = MyPDO::getInstance()->prepare("SELECT * FROM prj_img where id = 1 ");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $_GET['id']);
    $stmt->execute();


    $blob= $stmt->fetch();
    $img = $blob['name'];
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($img) .'" />';
}
```